# Is mutual information symmetric under conditioning?

Tags: mutual-information

Cover defines conditional mutual information as I(X; Y|Z) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y,Z), which I found confusing, as I would have expected I(X; Y|Z) = H(X) - H(X|Y,Z).

So I started trying to see which of 1) I(X|Z;Y), 2) I(X;Y|Z), and 3) I(X|Z;Y|Z) are equal.

Expanding each of these mutual informations out, we obtain:

1A) I(X|Z;Y) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y,Z)

1B)          = H(Y) - H(Y|X,Z).

2A) I(X;Y|Z) = H(Y|Z) - H(Y|X,Z)

2B)          = H(X) - H(X|Y,Z)

3A) I(X|Z;Y|Z) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y,Z)

3B)            = H(Y|Z) - H(Y|X,Z)

Equating (1A) and (3A) shows (1)=(3), and equating (2A) and (3B) shows (2) = (3), which should imply (1)=(2), *but* (1A) =/= (2B), as H(X)=/=H(X|Z) in general.

So I've made a mistake somewhere, but can't tell where it is.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!